# Books that provide justifications of perturbations and asymptotic methods.

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I am looking for books which provide justifications (proofs of appropriate theorems ) of various perturbation methods.
In particular I would like to study about justification of matched asymptotic expansions, multiply scales,
WKB, Poincare method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What level of rigor are you looking for? I would think the standard reference for these is Bender & Orszag, but it is admittedly a bit light on proofs, being aimed primarily toward engineers and physicists.

Comment: The highest one. Bender & Orszag contains a few proofs.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a nice source to base your search on is

C. Kuehn, *Multiple Time Scale Dynamics*, Springer (2015), ISBN 978-3-319-12315-8, [[link]](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319123158).

The book is very extensive concerning perturbation methods. In addition, it not only contains proofs, but also an extensive literature section, which guides you to literature where necessary proofs can be found.